# Why is aws cli giving me a connection reset by peer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

Trying to use aws cli to push a docker container. Getting connection reset. Not sure why?

```
 ecs-cli compose --project-name blah service up --create-log-groups --cluster-config blah --timeout 20

WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=expose service name=app
WARN[0000] Ignoring the ip address while transforming it to task definition  container=app portMapping="0.0.0.0:8080:8080"
WARN[0000] Ignoring the ip address while transforming it to task definition  container=app portMapping="0.0.0.0:8080:8080"
INFO[0000] Using ECS task definition                     TaskDefinition="blah:2"
WARN[0000] No log groups to create; no containers use 'awslogs' 
INFO[0001] Updated ECS service successfully              desiredCount=1 force-deployment=false service=blah
INFO[0047] (service blah) has started 1 tasks: (task d4d52496-057a-4b24-878a-4cf654085eff).  timestamp="2019-05-24 18:15:02 +0000 UTC"
INFO[0125] (service blah) has started 1 tasks: (task 9484000f-4a4d-4b2d-8fdb-a9668012d6ae).  timestamp="2019-05-24 18:16:23 +0000 UTC"
INFO[0202] (service blah) has started 1 tasks: (task f13dea68-e996-40ce-a44f-be266219b001).  timestamp="2019-05-24 18:17:32 +0000 UTC"
ERRO[0392] Error describing service                      error="RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post https://ecs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/: read tcp 192.168.1.231:53094->52.119.169.134:443: read: connection reset by peer" service=blah
FATA[0392] RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://ecs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/: read tcp 192.168.1.231:53094->52.119.169.134:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

Comment: I usually see this message when there is a network issue and there is a loss in connectivity... how long is this operation taking?

Comment: Not sure but the timeout is at 20 min. Before it was at 5 minutes and same issue.

Comment: Can you try it from a different network? For example, home vs work, or even tethered via a phone, just to see whether it is network-related?